# One character 2 colors diagonal

Tags: html, css

i need a one character "d" in 2 colors, but diagonal, no gradient.

Im using this CSS code:

```
.gradient_text_class {
  font-size: 72px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(50deg, #2f3441 50%, #ffffff 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

I was looking in codepen or jsfiddler for examples, but i cant find what i want.

Comment: replace `50deg` with `to bottom left` or `to bottom right` or any other combincation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `display:inline-block` to the h1 tag.
and the solution is this:

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, blue 50%, pink 50%);
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>D</h1>
```

If you dont add the display:inline-block the total width will be 100% and you will get the result only when the h1 is placed inside center

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, blue 50%, pink 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1>D</h1>
</center>
```